# Changing the value of elements in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

My program crashes once it reaches this function in my code. I printed the arrays in the function that are going in and commented out everything else and 
they are getting passed correctly. I can't figure out why it crashes here.

The arrays are numbers in ascending order. 
Maybe my loops or if statements are not right? I think maybe I'm not correctly changing the value in the array at index "d" when it reaches `attackerArmy[d] = '0'; //represent 0 as defeated` ?

```
long int defeatedArmies(long int* attackerArmy, long int* defenderArmy, long int size){

    long int i,j,defeated = 0,d;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){

        //loop for the highest attack value that is lower than defender
            if(attackerArmy[j] < defenderArmy[i])
                d = j; // save the index where it is highest

            if(attackerArmy[j] > defenderArmy[i])
            //no point in checking unnecessary values
                break;
        }
        attackerArmy[d] = '0'; //represent 0 as defeated
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(attackerArmy[i] == 0) //count how many defeated armies happened
            defeated++;
    }
return defeated;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**
if `attackerArmy[j] >= defenderArmy[i]` is true, `d` remains uninitialized causing the undefined behavior when you access its value in `attackerArmy[d] = '0';`.

**Possible fix**
Initialize `d` when you declare it.

**ex:**

```
long int d = -1L;
...
if(d != -1L) attackerArmy[d] = '0';
```

Comment: ah yes, didn't think about that. there's one fix. it doesn't crash so far. But now when I try printing the new array (attackerArmy) where some things could be zeroed out after it leaves the first two loops. It is filled with a bunch of different numbers that weren't in either array before

Comment: @Hispazn This sounds like a different problem. Is that new number 48 (0x30)? Did you mean '0' and not 0 or '\0' in line attackerArmy[d] = '0';?

Comment: yes :O and can you explain to me the difference between '0' and 0 ? I know \0 is just null character, yes?

Comment: @Hispazn `'0'` is character literal for printable character 0 and its value in [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is **not** zero. (Just like `'a'` is printable character a and its ascii values in non-zero). `0` OTOH is integer literal with value 0. `'\0'` is a nul cahracter literal with value 0 in ascii table.